# error writing to -: Invalid argument }

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qtcore

I get this error in qt creator while build project. This error is generated in different files means every time error is change to next .cpp file.

Error appears randomly in last of .cpp file near `}`(closing braces). I have clean the solution and build many times but error comes again .

Comment: Please edit the post and show the code.

Comment: T-Heron this not comes in only single files . Randomly it change the class and display error in last of class near } braces.

Comment: Do you write ; after this ?

Comment: @pravin Typically, in errors, there are line number where it occurred. Moreover, how do you expect us to tell you what the error is, without seeing _any_ code. Consider manufacturing [mcve].

Comment: @Andrei no, no ; after this

Answer (score 1):

Error is solved, after restarting the Qt-Creator.I think this might me problem 
of Qt creator.

Answer (score 0):

Check the *.pro file.
This error can arise because qmake looks for not existing file at the end of the list after a symbol "\".
Remove the last symbol "\".

For example maybe you have in pro-file:

```
HEADERS += file1.hpp \
       file2.hpp \
       file3.hpp \
```

You need to change the code as follows :

```
HEADERS += file1.hpp \
       file2.hpp \
       file3.hpp
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you delete the Release and Debug directories in your project.I meet this problem after I delete them.Enabling shadow build may work.